# Diffeomorphism of $S_n = \{(x,y,z,w) \in \mathbb{R}^4 \mid x^n+y^n+z^n+w^n=1\}$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

Let $S_n = \{(x,y,z,w) \in \mathbb{R}^4 \mid x^n+y^n+z^n+w^n=1\}$, then $S_n$ is $3$-manifold.

I want to know the condition about $n$ for $S_2$ and $S_n$ to be diffeomorphic, and I could prove
if $n$ is even, then $S_2 \simeq S_n$(Diffeomorphism).

But I'm not sure how to prove that if $n$ is odd, then $S_2 \not \simeq S_n$.

Is this correct? And how can I prove this? Thanks in advance!

(In my thought, proving $S_1 \not \simeq S_2$ and $S_1 \simeq S_n$ is how to prove it to be.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When $n$ is odd, $S_n$ contains the line

$$L = \{  (-s, s, 0, 1) : s\in \mathbb R\}$$

is thus is not compact. Hence $S_n$ is not homeomorphic to $S^2$, which is compact.